# pythonでExcelのcsvファイルの読み取りについて

Tags: python, csv

実現したいこと
pythonでcsvファイルを読み込んだ後、E列だけを取り出して、その数値を１０以上で場合分けし、E列の１０以上の数値がいくつあるかを数えられるようなものを作りたいと考えております。

問題点
pythonでcsvファイルの読み込みには成功したものの、列単体だけの読み込みがうまくいきません。
また、for文で場合分けした後１０以上の数値がいくつあるのかを数える作業がうまくいきません。その際はsumを使用したらよいのか、counterでカウントしたらよいのか教えていただきたいです。

どうかよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 現状のプログラムを追記していただくことは可能ですか？　回答者がプログラムをイチから書くのは手間であるため、たたき台となるプログラムがあった方が回答が集まりやすくなります。「編集」から自由に追記できますのでお試しください。

Answer (score 1):

後々何かに加工するのでなければ、列単体で取り出すより、各行からその都度取り出した方が早そうです。

例えばこんな`data.csv`ファイルがあるとします。

```
0,1,2,3, 4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,40,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3, 4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,14,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3, 4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,10,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3, 4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,24,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3, 4,5,6,7,8,9
0,1,2,3,34,5,6,7,8,9
```

こうしたプログラムで10以上の数値をカウントできます。

```
import csv

csvdata = []
with open('data.csv', mode='r', encoding='shift_jis') as fp:
    csvdata = list(csv.reader(fp))

ge10count = 0
for row in csvdata:
    colE = int(row[4])
    if colE >= 10:
        ge10count += 1

print(ge10count)
```

後で何かに加工するので抽出しておきたい場合は、こちらの記事を参考に。
[Pythonで二次元配列の中の各要素のn番目だけを取り出して、要素として並べたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/47331/26370)

読み込んだ後のプログラムを以下のようにします。

```
columnE = [row[4] for row in csvdata]

ge10count2 = 0
for strE in columnE:
    colE = int(strE)
    if colE >= 10:
        ge10count2 += 1

print(ge10count2)
```

Comment: 丁寧に教えていただきありがとうございます。追加でお尋ねしたいのですが
    import csv
    
    f = open("test2.csv", "r",)
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
    
    f.close()　　現在このような形でcsvファイルを読み込んでおり、回答していただいた内容を基に  
    import csv
    
    f = open("test2.csv", "r",)
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
    
    f.close()

Comment: コメントは使い勝手が悪いので、質問に追記してもらった方が良いですよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。